# C/C++ Retrieving notification of a closed windows explorer window

Tags: c++, c, windows-explorer

I have an application - that opens a Windows Explorer window at a specific directory path that I have specified right after it launches.

Is there any way that I can get some kind of a notification in my application whenever that Windows Explorer window has been closed?

Any help regarding this would be helpful.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20111026-00/?p=9263

Comment: As an alternative to detecting when Explorer window is closed, you might check out whether it's possible to host that view in your own window.

Answer (score 2):

You can subscribe to open/close events of Explorer windows with IShell­Windows. Details you can find there: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130614-00/?p=4083/